# How to align list element dynamically to its neighbor's height using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a grid which will get expand on click. I need them to align and adjust the height accordingly.

[image: Example]

When I click my nth child of li its not aligned properly. Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

I need like this [image]

**CSS**

```
ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:
}
ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ddd;
    margin:1px;
    float:left;
}
li.large{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1wpjdqax/2/)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: hey u are looking at the output in jsfiddle check it on some fullpage or mobile width it is very different so u want to align them properly in all resolutions???

Comment: its on full page want it responsive the left elements working perfect whereas not the right one.

Comment: Dude its happening dynamically on click check the fiddle for more reference

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/?

Comment: it didn't work in my case when i add my dynamic class height sticks to same since it is position absolute

Comment: Is this what you mean... http://jsfiddle.net/x7qvk50c/

Comment: @BA_Webimax what you did was great but I need it to be expand in the same place

Answer (score 0):

I checked out your JSFiddle and toyed with your CSS class values. I think the issue is related to positioning caused by your padding and margin values. Changing the value for the li.large margin to 2 px seems to achieve your desired result:

```
li.large{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:2px !important;
}
```

Try those values and see if you get whate you were looking for.

Comment: Hey thanks but still my small thumbnail are not aligned to my large ones height